# how to simplify v-lookup to compare data among different tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a v-lookup formula to compare data among different sheets (Sheet-1 Column A, B, C) with Sheet-2 Column-A
But I am writing a very lengthy formula to do the comparison and i want to simplify that

```
IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[[#All],[Column-1]],Table2[[#All],[Column-1]],1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[[#All],[Column-2]],Table2[[#All],[Column-1]],1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[[#All],[Column-3]],Table2[[#All],[Column-1]],1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? This includes example data.

Comment: I tried IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[[#All],[Column-1]],Table1[[#All],[Column-2]],Table1[[#All],[Column-3]],Table2[[#All],[Column-1]],1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No") 
But it is throwing error

Comment: What is you end goal? To state "Yes" only when all three values (column-1 to column-3) are present in Table-2?

Comment: Any one of the value.. Its a OR condition

Answer (score 1):

Try the following array formula...

[image]

D3, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table1[@[Column-1]:[Column-3]],Table2[Column-1],0))),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, if it is for the complete column:

`IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!B:B,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet2!B:B,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet2!B:B,1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No")`

If you want to reduce, then use the Name Manager to place:

```
A1 = Table1[[#All],[Column-1]]
B1 = Table1[[#All],[Column-2]]
C1 = Table1[[#All],[Column-3]]
B2 = Table2[[#All],[Column-1]]
```

Then:

`IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,B2,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,B2,1,FALSE))=FALSE,ISNA(VLOOKUP(C1,B2,1,FALSE))=FALSE),"Yes","No")`

Even, you can avoid to have all this `ISNA` function as if there is one TRUE, everything will be true.